# Getting indices of sorting integer array

Tags: sorting, pseudocode

i have an array with integers, which i need to sort. however the result should not contain the integer values, but the indices. i.e. the new order of the old array.

for example: [10, 20, 30]

should result in: [2, 1, 0]

what is an optimized algorithm to achieve this?

Comment: this is what most implementations of sorting algorithms would do. have you attempted anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with any sorting algorithm, if you convert each element to a tuple of `(value, position)` and sort this.

That is,  `[10, 20, 30]` would become `[(10, 0), (20, 1), (30, 2)]`. You'd then sort this array using a comparator that looks at the first element of the tuples, giving you `[(30, 2), (20, 1), (10, 0)]`. From this, you can simply grab the second element of each tuple to get what you want, `[2, 1, 0]`. (Under the assumption you want reverse sorting.)

Answer (score 0):

Won't be different from any other sorting algorithm, just modify it so that it builds or takes in an array of indices and then manipulates both the data and array of indices instead of just the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a array of pointers to the original array of integers, perform a merge sort or what ever sorting algorithm you find most suiting (uses the value at the pointer) then just run down the list calculating the indicies based on each pointers relative address to the beginning of the allocated block containing the original array of integers.